# When restoring Termux from a backup, how can I specify which shell Termux to use (sh or bash) and how to specify which init files this shell to use?

Tags: termux

Because the shell(s) below of Termux are throwing error continously which cannot be canceled with ctrl-c or other means - due to a vim which cannot find/read .vimrc - and since shell actions in Failsafe mode are also of no help, I am looking for a way to control from outside of Termux what Termux will do after it is launched. Regards.